# How can I prevent VS Code from automatically adding quotes after = for attributes in HTML?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, settings

In VS Code, whenever I type in an attribute and an `=` within an HTML file/section, the code editor automatically adds subsequent following quotes. E.g. `<label for=` immediately becomes `<label for=""`.

I know this is helpful for some, but I'd like to turn off that functionality - I can't seem to unlearn two decades of typing quotes in myself.

I've tried toggling every setting with "quote" in the name, and a number of other "auto" settings, but no luck. I've tried every setting I can think of and gone through so many different stack answers so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"html.autoCreateQuotes": false
```

The setting's description:

> Enable/disable auto creation of quotes for HTML attribute assignment. The type of quotes can be configured by `#html.completion.attributeDefaultValue#`.

Quotes will still be added though if you accept a suggestion for the attribute name itself. But they will no longer be added if you type the attribute name yourself and then type `=`.

Comment: Dang, not sure why I struggled to find that. THANK YOU!